# android studio emulator: click on panel buttons causes emulator closes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

```
Android Studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-64-generic
```

[image: emulator]

I have updated my android studio, and after that, when I click on any buttons on the left panel of my emulator, or even when I press `ctrl + M` to open developer menu, emulator closes suddenly.

What I have tested so far (non of them working):

```
1. installing previous version of android studio
2. choosing another avd
3. choosing another system image (api 28)
4. uninstalling android studio and installing again
5. invalidate/resetting cache
```

Update:

When emulator closes, I get this in the event log:

```
2:47 PM Emulator: [26918:26918:0924/144702.703700:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

2:47 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

The issue has been discussed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/d6gnrn/android_emulator_2920_crashes_on_fedora_wayland/)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to disable sandbox and fix this issue by setting environment variable: QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX to 1:

```
export QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with Android Studio 3.5.1 and Ubuntu. I updated the emulator from 29.1.12 (that worked perfectly) to 29.2.1.

Fortunately I had a second computer with the previous version of the emulator (29.1.12), so I copied it from /root/Android/Sdk/emulator (the default location) and then replaced it. The problem is that it is very difficult to find old versions of the emulator. If you try with older versions than this, it might not work, so it has to be 29.1.12. I also recommend to wipe out the the virtual device before starting it.
The next time, if you really want to uninstall Android Studio and install a previous version, make sure that you delete the /root/Android directory.

Comment: Did you follow the steps? It worked for me in a couple of computers.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same and running Android Studio without sudo worked for me.