# android studio emulator shuts down when clicking on the pannel buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am getting a problem these days with my emulator. When I click on the panel buttons, my emulator will shut down. I have started searching the causes of that problem online and got [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078046/android-studio-emulator-click-on-panel-buttons-causes-emulator-closes) that i may change the environment variable to solve the problem, but it doesn't.

What I have tried as well is :

```
uninstall my emulator and delete all its folders and reinstall
update my android studio
```

I am using the latest version of android studio, `2021.1.1 Patch 1` all versions of emulators that I've installed act in the same way.

What can be the cause of that problem and how can I solve it please ?

Comment: I suggest to use another emulator program

Comment: How can l do it, please ?

Comment: For example Genymotion Free https://www.genymotion.com/download/ works beter than Android Studio emulator. Install it, then register a Personal account to use it for free

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll try it.

Comment: The only thing to note is that newest versions now leave a watermark on the nav bar when you make screenshots. If you want to avoid this, install version 3.1.2 or older https://filehippo.com/es/download_genymotion/3.1.2/

Comment: Okay, understood. Thanks

Comment: Hi dude. I am trying the emulator but it's really slow to launch or execute an app. I've installed 3 emulators with up to 8gb of ram but they are all slow. Is it normal while android studio emulator was not like that ?

Comment: Damn, that's strange, Genymotion is lighter than AS and should work faster. What OS are you using? Which version of VirtualBox do you have?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.4 and I have just installed virtual box so the latest version. Edit: virtualbox version is 6.1

Comment: That should be OK. Genymotion also recommends using same ADB as Android Studio https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/02_Application/#use-third-party-adbsdk, and make sure `Intel VT-x`, `AMD-V` and/or `SVM` is enabled.

Comment: If everything fails, try the settings of the beginning of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZKiqJyLBkU

Comment: I have already configured the ADB to be using the one of android studio. And Intel VT-x is already enabled. I will try again after rebooting my computer and see, if it still doesn't work, I will try those settings. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Did it work?

Comment: Hello brother, yes it's a little bit good now and I hope it'll keep being like that :). Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Did rebooting fix it or was it something else? I'm asking just in case someone reads this and has similar issues with Genymotion

Comment: It's pretty complicated to answer this. Because I rebooted and applied also those configs. By the way, it'll be helpful also to know how to install apps from playstore because there is no playstore in there and when I want to download it, nothing happens

Comment: I see. Well, to install Google Apps, just use the button at the side of the emulator called "Open Gapps" and it will setup automatically. If you need old emulators (i believe Genymotion nowadays supports from android 4.4) there are Github Gists online with links to ovas that can be installed easily, like this one https://gist.github.com/palagend/de482722d5903ff84288ea8a11408f65

Comment: Yep. Everything is alright now. Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked!